# Need SEO help with our sitemap.xml Google Index rate

Tags: seo, index

We have a Magento multi-store setup for 3 stores/domains built on October, 2013. Since then we have great google sitemap.xml index rates for over 90% across all 3 domains. On 2/25/2014, we added another domain into the same magento installation. The sitemap.xml index rate for the original 3 domains dropped significantly afterward.(Our mistake to include every single SKUs we have into the 4th domain) After we discovered the problem, we took out the 4th domain and changed everyting back to before. We waited for couple weeks, 2 of the websites are back on track on sitemap.xml with 90% index rate. For the other domain, we tried everything we could to increase the index rate without any luck. It's been over one month after we took out the 4th domain, somehow Google only indexed 1% of the sitemap.xml and kept the rate since.

1. Our configurations:

   - Magento Configurations are the same across all 3 stores/domains
   - All 3 domains using different IP addresses. (We implemented this after the big drop on index rate)
   - 3 websites share some of the products and brands we carry
   - All 3 domains shares same .htaccess and robot.txt
   - All of our domains are more than 5 years old.
   - We use Nexcess for Magento hosting. (Updated for reference.)

Question:
What else might causing google to not index the 3rd domain's sitemap.xml?

FYI: We are able to manually submit urls in webmaster tools for google to index it.

Comment: How many products do your stores carry? Are they the same on each store?

Comment: Store1: 40k SKUs, Store2: 5.7k SKUs, Store3: 23k SKUs. They share some of the SKUs. Store3 is the one that having problems now.

Answer (score 2):

You are quite lucky you were reindexed in weeks, for most it takes months - normally 3-6mths. Regardless of what anyone says, there are no guarantees with indexing and ranking, only best practices, likely they have flagged that domain. Too many factors come in to play on the business and technology side, one of the factors is the hosting company. We use top tier providers but they are 2-5x slower than lower tier providers, so we used a special architecture from a third party making a site look bigger than it is. Without making your other domain 'look' bigger Google loses interest, especially if flagged.

The age of the domain makes no difference, a brand new domain was listing the same products next to eBay and Amazon first page. Google will see through full page caches so if your dynamic loads are more than 1-2s you will have a problem. There are too many factors to go through, so without enterprise style hosting -or- knowing the business tricks to mitigate most of these issues (only a handful know these), you will have to go the trial and error route over the coming months - checking once a week for any changes.

Lastly, this is a business problem not a technical problem, we never did find where to direct people for these as this is not the forum for it.

Comment: We use Nexcess for Magento hosting, and thank you for the information. It is really hard to find a place to post this kind of question and even harder to get a respond.